# Syncing week reputation with StackExchange is not right

Tags: discussion, reputation, user-rank

In week rank page, my week reputation is still showing yesterday's reputation. Is it updated real-time or in daily basis? I tried to sync my account, but still no effect. Anyone know why?

Also, when is it updated? At which timezone?

Comment: it gets updated after the end of each day.

Comment: SE uses UTC so the day rolls over at 0000 UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In week rank page, my week reputation is still showing yesterday's reputation

That's right. It is not a live count.